# ListView Not Showing in Fullscreen when Using smart android T.V

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tv

I am in trouble. I have VideoView that always appear on the screen and a ListView that will show only if touch on screen is detected. My problem is that when ever I do full screen by adjusting in the manifest...

```
 <application
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" >
```

...when I run my application (note: I install on smart Android TV box) the ListView is not showing but when I random click on screen the item is being toast. I don't know why it behave like this when I do full screen but in the mobile device it works fine.

Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vdo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: change in listview android:layout_height="wrap_content" instead of android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: not working on T.V box

Comment: Well, it's declared to be invisible: `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: @StenSoft, Thank you it works